# Can't really find some chords in this song, are they that hard or i'm the noob?

Tags: chords, chord-progressions, jazz, chord-voicings

Every time i hear a song or a version of a particular song i like i try to get it by ear but there is something here that is odd, i really can't get to sound like the girl in the following video.

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://music.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Sounds fairly standard to me, with occasional extensions to the original chords. The song was originally written in 3/4 by the way. But this will be closed, as it doesn't fit the remit of the site.

Comment: in 3/4… "Fly me to moon & let swing among stars…"  it's a bit reminiscent of Life's a Bowl of Cherries in 5/4 ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin - no change in words for either time sig, actually...  Only 'play', not swing!

Comment: Sorry ;)) It was just based on the old Jazzer's joke, sing Life's a Bowl of Cherries in 5/4  - - "Life's a Bowl of f***ing Cherries"